# Files hidden unless I cd from 2 folders away

Tags: linux, centos, files, software-installation

I have a CentOS7 virtual machine that I created to run some software. The software is installed at `Downloads/folder1/folder2` under a non-root profile. Folder names are changed and the downloads location was unintentional - I'm brand new to Linux.

There are two `.xml` files that are used to configure the software that are hidden appear to not exist unless I `cd /Downloads` and then `cd /folder1/folder2`. If I jump the whole way `cd /Downloads/folder1/folder2` the files are not there. If I go one folder at a time they're not there.

The root account has the same issue.

I don't know how to explain this behavior, but I was hoping someone here much smarter than me might be able to explain this. I'm assuming it's some sort of bug.

I have the GNOME desktop environment installed, and the files cannot be seen in the GUI at all only through terminal and using `cd /folder1/folder2` starting in `/Downloads`.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld ~/Downloads ~/Downloads/folder1 ~/Downloads/folder1/folder2`?

Comment: Note that `/folder1/folder2` is an absolute path, not relative. So `cd /folder1/folder2` will put you under `/`, not under `Downloads`. You may be looking at distinct locations.

Answer (score 1):

`/Downloads/folder1/folder2` is not the same as `/folder1/folder2`.  When you do

```
cd /folder1/folder2
```

and see your files, then you are not in `/Downloads/folder1/folder2` but in `/folder1/folder2`

Comment: way to much folder in this answer

Comment: @Kiwy Unfortunately, it's inherited from the question.

Comment: You somehow manage to make it readable though